# Logger Output Time Display

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to delete the time from a logger output? I know you can use the replace function, but this is inefficient in replacing the time down to the second. I just want to keep the text from the log.

Example output using replace:

- 01:23:23  : text

Example output without replace function:

- Tue Oct 20 01:23:23 EDT 2020 INFO: text

Answer (score 0):

### Instead of logging the data, you can e.g. write it into a spreadsheet

In this case only the text itself will be written - not the date stamp.

Sample:

```
myValues= [1,2,3];
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name);
for (var i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++){
 sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(myValues[i]);
}
```